# QEventLoop и async/await

Tags: c++, qt

В своем проекте пытаюсь реализовать подобие механизма `async/await` операций на Qt c использование `QEventLoop`. Приведу простейший пример окна с одной кнопкой, по нажатию которой должен вызывать код, не блокирующий основной (GUI) поток.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("button",this);
    connect(button,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::onClicked);
}
void MainWindow::onClicked()
{
    qDebug() << time() << " onClicked start ";

    QEventLoop loop;
    QtConcurrent::run([&loop]() {
        qDebug() << time() << " Thread start: " << (void*)QThread::currentThread();
        //doSomething
        QThread::currentThread()->sleep(10);
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&loop,"quit",Qt::QueuedConnection)
        qDebug() << time() << " Thread finish: " << (void*)QThread::currentThread();
    });

    loop.exec();

    qDebug() << time() << " onClicked finish ";
}
```

При однократном нажатии все замечательно, `QtConcurrent` запустит задачу, которая выполнится в  отдельном потоке, а `loop.exec()` остановит выполнение функции, но не заблокирует `EventLoop` всего приложения, окно будет активно, кнопку можно будет нажать еще.
В отладчике будет выведено, примерно следующее:

```
16:57:08.774  onClicked start 
16:57:08.775  Thread start:  0xa83230
16:57:18.775  Thread finish:  0xa83230
16:57:18.775  onClicked finish
```

Если нажать кнопку несколько раз, то слот вызовется несколько раз и при каждом вызове создадутся объекты `QEventLoop`, которые остановят выполнение слота в ожидании окончания асинхронных задач, что очевидно.
**НО**
Выход из цикла обработки событий у этих объектов произойдет одновременно по окончанию последней асинхронной задачи, т.е. после вызова последнего слота `quit()`
В отладчике следующее:

```
17:26:28.464  onClicked start 
17:26:28.464  Thread start:  0xa83230
17:26:30.988  onClicked start 
17:26:30.988  Thread start:  0x8dae20
17:26:37.549  onClicked start 
17:26:37.549  Thread start:  0xa349c0
17:26:38.464  Thread finish:  0xa83230
17:26:40.989  Thread finish:  0x8dae20
17:26:47.549  Thread finish:  0xa349c0
17:26:47.549  onClicked finish 
17:26:47.549  onClicked finish 
17:26:47.549  onClicked finish
```

**Вопрос**: почему при создании нескольких объектов `QEventLoop`, они заканчивают свои циклы обработки только после вызова слота `quit()` каждого из объектов и как это изменить?

Answer (score 2):

В Qt используется приватный мьютекс у объекта потока (`QThread`) с атомарным счётчиком ссылок (`QAtomicInt`):

```
// qeventloop.cpp, стр. 164
QMutexLocker locker(&static_cast<QThreadPrivate *>
    (QObjectPrivate::get(d->threadData->thread))->mutex);
```

Соответственно, если поток, в котором существуют экземпляры `QEventLoop`, один и тот же, то покуда счётчик ссылок `quitLockRef` (см. файл qeventloop_p.h) не уйдёт в ноль, каждый инстанс `QEventLoop` будет бесконечно крутиться в собственном цикле.

Для организации асинхронной реакции на завершение работы `QtConcurrent` лучше всего подходит `QFutureWatcher`:

```
void MainWindow::onClicked() {
    qDebug() << time() << " onClicked start ";

    QFutureWatcher<void> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>(this);
    connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished
        , this, [this,watcher]() {

        qDebug() << time() << " onClicked finish ";
        watcher->deleteLater();
    });

    QFuture<void> future
        = QtConcurrent::run([this]() {

            qDebug() << time() << " Thread start: "
                << (void*)QThread::currentThread();

            //doSomething
            QThread::currentThread()->sleep(10);

            qDebug() << time() << " Thread finish: "
                << (void*)QThread::currentThread();
    });

    watcher->setFuture(future);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потоки не виноваты. На их месте мог быть и отложенный вызов какого-нибудь QTimer::singleShot(). 
Просто происходит рекурсивный вызов.

- 17:26:28.464  onClicked start - 1 - вызван из главного QEventLoop приложения
- 17:26:30.988       onClicked start - 2 - вызван из первого вложенного QEventLoop
- 17:26:37.549               onClicked start - 3 - вызван из второго вложенного QEventLoop
- 17:26:47.549               onClicked finish - 3
- 17:26:47.549       onClicked finish - 2
- 17:26:47.549  onClicked finish - 1