# Создать QIODevice (QSerialPort) в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread

Класс `QSerialPort`, насколько я понимаю, не предназначен для работы с `QThread`. Поэтому делаю класс наследник который сможет работать с `QThread`, в котором добавляю недостающие сигналы и слоты. И хочу узнать все ли я сделал правильно, все ли должно работать? нет ли в коде "велосипедов"? Обязателен ли m_loop?

**serialportthread.h**

```
#ifndef MYSERIALPORT_H
#define MYSERIALPORT_H

#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QSerialPort>

class SerialPortThread : public QSerialPort
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QEventLoop m_loop;  // for thread run
public:
    struct Settings {
        QString name;
        qint32 baudRate;
        QString stringBaudRate;
        QSerialPort::DataBits dataBits;
        QString stringDataBits;
        QSerialPort::Parity parity;
        QString stringParity;
        QSerialPort::StopBits stopBits;
        QString stringStopBits;
        QSerialPort::FlowControl flowControl;
        QString stringFlowControl;
    };

    SerialPortThread(Settings s, QObject *parent = nullptr);
public slots:
    void start();
    void stop();
    void txMsg(QByteArray txMsg);
signals:
    void stoped(int status);
    void started();
    void rxMsg(QByteArray rxMsg);
};

#endif // MYSERIALPORT_H
```

**serialportthread.cpp**

```
#include "serialportthread.h"

SerialPortThread::SerialPortThread(Settings s, QObject *parent)
    : QSerialPort(s.name, parent)
{
    setBaudRate(s.baudRate);
    setDataBits(s.dataBits);
    setParity(s.parity);
    setStopBits(s.stopBits);
    setFlowControl(s.flowControl);
    connect(this, &QSerialPort::readyRead, [this] {
        auto msg = readAll();
        emit rxMsg(msg);
    });
    connect(this, &SerialPortThread::stoped, [this] () { m_loop.exit(); });
}

void SerialPortThread::start()
{
    if (!open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        emit stoped(1); // error
        return;
    }
    emit started();
    m_loop.exec();
}

void SerialPortThread::stop()
{
    if (isOpen()) {
        close();
    }
    m_loop.exit();
    emit stoped(0);
}

void SerialPortThread::txMsg(QByteArray txMsg)
{
    write(txMsg);
}
```

И примерный код для контроллеров потока:

```
void ControllerThreads::openDevice(SerialPortThread::Settings settings)
{
    SerialPortThread *comPort = new SerialPortThread(settings);
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    comPort->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, comPort, &SerialPortThread::start);
    connect(comPort, &SerialPortThread::rxMsg, this, &ControllerThreads::rxDevice);
    connect(comPort, &SerialPortThread::stoped,
            [=] (int i) { qDebug() << "finished:" << i; });
    connect(comPort, &SerialPortThread::stoped,
            comPort, &SerialPortThread::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, comPort, &SerialPortThread::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
    thread->start();
}
```

Comment: Не вижу проблем.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651932/3380)

Comment: А как ваш поток завершаться будет? Я про `QThread`. И ещё, насколько я помню, запуская `QThread` вы как раз QEventLoop и запускаете. То есть здесь у вас два QEventLoop получается.

Comment: @vegorov при вызове `thread->start();` вызвется связанный слот `SerialPortThread::start`, и насколько я понимаю, если функция `start` завершится, то вызвется сигнал `&QThread::finished` и поток закончит работу. Что бы избежать завершении функции, вызываю `m_loop.exec();`. Но возможно я ошибаюсь.

Comment: посмотрите тут как реализована работа в потоке (первые два примера) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-examples.html