# Соединить слот с индексом к объекту в массиве (возможно std::bind)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++11, c++14

Создал класс для работы с девайсами в разных потоках( [Создать QIODevice (QSerialPort) в отдельном потоке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993704/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-qiodevice-qserialport-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5)). Теперь думаю как связать номер девайса с объектом у которого нужно вызвать слот `txToDevice`.

**Класс контроллер потоков.**

```
class ControllerThreads : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ControllerThreads(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void rxFromDevice(Devices *dev);
    void __txToDevice(int device, QByteArray tx);
public slots:
    void openDevice(int device, SerialPortThread::Settings settings);
    void stopDevice(int device);
    void txToDevice(int device, QByteArray tx);
protected slots:
    void rxDevice(QByteArray rx);
private:
    std::array<QByteArray, Devices::COUNT> m_buff;
    std::array<SerialPortThread *, Devices::COUNT> m_comPort { };
    void searchMsg(uint type, QByteArray rx);
};
```

**И вот создания потока, и не знаю как связать каждое устройство со своим номером девайса**

```
void ControllerThreads::openDevice(uint device, SerialPortThread::Settings settings)
{
    Q_ASSERT(device < VizovDevices::COUNT);
    Q_ASSERT(!m_comPort[device]);
    SerialPortThread *comPort = new SerialPortThread(settings);
    m_comPort[device] = comPort;
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    comPort->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, comPort, &SerialPortThread::start);
    connect(comPort, &SerialPortThread::rxMsg, this, &ControllerThreads::rxDevice);
    connect(comPort, &SerialPortThread::stoped,
            [=] (int i) { qDebug() << "finished:" << i; });
    connect(comPort, &SerialPortThread::stoped,
            comPort, &SerialPortThread::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, comPort, &SerialPortThread::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
    // help me
    connect(this, &ControllerThreads::__txToDevice/*device*/, comPort, &SerialPortThread::txMsg);
    thread->start();
}

void ControllerThreads::txToDevice(int device, QByteArray tx)
{
    emit __txToDevice(device, tx);
}
```

Как вариант можно создать кучу `__txToDeviceX`:

```
void __txToDevice1(QByteArray tx);
void __txToDevice2(QByteArray tx);
void __txToDevice3(QByteArray tx);
...
void __txToDeviceN(QByteArray tx);
void ControllerThreads::txToDevice(int device, QByteArray tx)
{
    if (device == 1) emit __txToDevice1(tx);
    if (device == 2) emit __txToDevice2(tx);
    if (device == 3) emit __txToDevice3(tx);
    ...
    if (device == N) emit __txToDeviceN(tx);
}
```

и уже однозначно привязать каждый объект `SerialPortThread` к `txToDevice`. Но думаю в с++11, а уж в с++14 наверняка будет механизм решающий мою задачу более изящно. Первое что приходит в голову - `std::bind`. Но во первых никогда не пользовался, и не знаю о подводных камнях. А во вторых не знаю насколько корректно работает `std::bind со сигналами/слотами Qt`.

Comment: Вам нужно сигнал каждого SerialPortThread привязать к сигналу ControllerThreads::txToDevice и при этом, чтобы первым аргументом был идентификатор из QSerialPort, внутри  SerialPortThread?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin мне нужно что бы `MainWindow` мог отправить через ф-цию `ControllerThreads::txToDevice` данные в любой `SerialPortThread`, к которым обращаться с помощью индекса `int device`. Тк `SerialPortThread` в другом потоке обращаться к ним могу только через слоты. Вот и думаю как сделать такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы не было многопоточности, можно было написать так:

```
connect(this, &ControllerThreads::__txToDevice, [&](int device, QByteArray tx){m_comPort[device]->txMsg(tx);});
```

Вам же нужно, чтобы метод выполнился к другом потоке.
Можно попробовать вызывать слот с помощью QMetaObject:

```
void ControllerThreads::txToDevice(int device, QByteArray tx) {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_comPort[device], "txMsg", Qt::AutoConnection, 
        Q_ARG(QByteArray, tx));
}
```

Comment: `connect(this, &ControllerThreads::__txToDevice, [&](int device, QByteArray tx){m_comPort[device]->txMsg(tx);}, Qt::QueuedConnection);` - разве могу обращаться к объекту если тот находится в другом потоке? ЗЫ: второй пример еще не разобрал

Comment: посмотрел второй вариант: с одной стороны круто, и можно много что капать в эту сторону, и вроде должно работать. С другой стороны такой стиль программирования (используя метаданные) мне не очень нравится.

Comment: так можно узнать, могу ли я в лямбда-функциях обращаться к объектам которые находятся в другом потоке?

Comment: @KtoTo думаю, что в лямбде не получится. Попробуйте второй вариант. 
Слот txMsg будет выполнен в потоке, которому принадлежит объект m_comPort[device]